# Capture url, browser and browser version, and put it in body of an email

Tags: javascript, email

I have a website with thousands of pages with all kinds of things that can go wrong as technology and devices progress (www.toilette-humor.com). I need to add a link on every page that will allow users to "REPORT A PROBLEM". So I need to capture the following info and have it email off to me:

- What URL they saw the problem on
- What Browser and Version they are using

and if possible...

- What Operating System they are using
- What Platform/Device they are using

I have found some code here to answer the first issue of capturing the URL and putting it in the body of an email, AND I found some other code for capturing the browser and version, but that code doesn't add it to an email.

I know absolutely nothing about writing Javascript what so ever. So I ask you all, how can I combine the two scripts, or is there a better solution.

Script One (Captures URL and add's it to body of email) found here: [How to write in 'mailto' body link to current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977165/how-to-write-in-mailto-body-link-to-current-page)

```
<head>
<script>
    function SendLinkByMail(href) {
        var subject= "Report a Problem";
        var body = "There is a problem with this webpage:\r\n\r\n<";
        body += window.location.href;
        body += ">";
        var uri = "mailto:?subject=";
        uri += encodeURIComponent(subject);
        uri += "&body=";
        uri += encodeURIComponent(body);
        window.location.href = uri;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p><a href="javascript:(function()%7BSendLinkByMail()%3B%7D)()%3B">Email link to this page</a></p>
</body>
```

Script Two (Captures Browser and Version) found here: [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)

```
<script>
    navigator.sayswho= (function(){
        var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
        M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
        if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
            tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
        }
        M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]:[navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
        if((tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
        return M.join(' ');
    })();
</script>
```

Thank you all in advance for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Where did you find the HTML bit? Looks like some extra code that you don't want `%7B` etc.

Comment: Look down a few comments on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977165/how-to-write-in-mailto-body-link-to-current-page

That code does work fine for me. Just need to figure out how to add more info to the body (browser and version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an FYI, you shouldn't be using javascript links, but we'll deal with that in a second.

If you want to add the userAgent to the body, you can do this:

```
function SendLinkByMail(href) {
    var subject= "Report a Problem";
    var body = "There is a problem with this webpage:\r\n\r\n<";
    body += window.location.href;
    body += ">";
    body += navigator.userAgent;
    var uri = "mailto:?subject=";
    uri += encodeURIComponent(subject);
    uri += "&body=";
    uri += encodeURIComponent(body);
    window.location.href = uri;
}
```

If you want to use that odd function you've got there, you could just change the `navigator.userAgent` line to read `navigator.sayswho()`.

Additionally, you should be attaching the action using an event listener:

```
<body>
    <p class="send-email">Email link to this page</p>
    <script>
        var send = document.getElementsByClassName('send-email')[0];
        send.attachEvent? send.attachEvent('click', SendLinkByMail) : send.addEventListener('click', SendLinkByMail);
    </script>
</body>
```

But this is still sort of a leaky way to send an e-mail since if the user uses a webmail client `mailto:` links are unlikely to work without extra setup work from the user.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 

I thought the mailto: might be an issue for that exact reason. The scripting above to date has been all that I could find so far. My Google Foo at this point has not been able to find a good piece of code to fix my issue. 

I am thinking I might need to change my direction to a form that could be populated with the info I need, and then submitted that way instead of going through the users email program, but that would be for another topic I suppose.

I will try your script above.

Thank you again

Comment: Yes, that did exactly what my title was looking for. 

I will look into a better way to do this next other then the mailto: issue that you brought up. 

Kind regards

Comment: @BGyver the "proper" way to do this is to send the mail from your backend but that's a massive can of worms to open.  This way does suffice for a set number of use-cases

Comment: @BGyver also if this works you should upvote/accept the answer so others know it's a working solution to the issue.